# ME feature for Webpshere liberty

Tags: websphere-liberty

Is there a separate feature which supports messaging engine on liberty profile or is it one of the jmsclient/server features which would let define ME on liberty. 
Any help highly appreciated

Thanks
RD

Answer (score 0):

To run JMS applications you will need the following features: for creating the messaging engine - `wasJmsServer-1.0`, for MDB  - feature `jmsMdb-3.1`, for JMS Client access - feature `wasJmsClient-1.1`. Probably the easiest is just to download and install extended package: [Liberty Extended Content](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/#asset/addons-8.5.5-wlp-developers-extended) which provides Web Services, JMS and MongoDB.